# Is my pandas DataFrame selection bug-free?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a very large group galaxy catalogue, and another with morphologies coming from Zoo Universe project. I have made an outer join, so I have now a DataFrame with a column 'Morph' where there can be NaN (from the outer join), 'U' (Galaxy zoo code for unknown) or a proper value.

Now I'm looking for groups (i.e. rows having the same 'Group' value) where all morphologies are known. Unfortunately, when I run my code, it finds none, which is very sad for me, but possible (I'm not able to find an example in 15 minutes of data examination by eye, but this is not a proof, considering the size of the catalogue).

The thing is: is my code bug-free?

Here is a mock example:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,'S'],[1,'E'],[1,'E'],[2,'U'],[2,'E'],[2,'S'],[3,np.nan],
                       [3,'E'],[3,'E'],[4,'U'],[4,'U'],[4,'U']], columns=['Group','Morph'])

df
```

[image]

And my code:

```
df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: (~x.Morph.isin(['U',np.nan]).any() ))
```

Which seems to work here:

[image]

First group being the only one without NaN nor 'U'. Is there a possibility that it works here by chance and that there is an error in my code which will not reveal itself in my simple example?

Comment: Once you have  done the groupby, you should be able to access the table by group: `df.groupby('Group').all().T['group name']` if you find elements here but not after the filter operation, the latter might be the problem...

Comment: I'm not quite sure to understand your answer, but I will try to investigate it. I have already exported data in a csv to be able to look for groups by eye, which was unsuccessful - nevertheless, as stated, due to catalogue size, I can't be sure.

Comment: @Matt - I think your code looks nice, maybe is possible a bit improve by `print (df.groupby('Group')['Morph'].filter(lambda x: (~x.isin(['U',np.nan]).any())))`. I add another solution for test, but it seems some problem in data (whitespaces `' U'` not `'U'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you solution works nice, I add alternative solution without `groupby` with double `booelan indexing` and `isin`:

```
print (df[df['Morph'].isin(['U',np.nan])])
    Group Morph
3       2     U
6       3   NaN
9       4     U
10      4     U
11      4     U

#unique is for faster isin if check unique values
idx = df.loc[df['Morph'].isin(['U',np.nan]), 'Group'].unique()
print (idx)
[2 3 4]

print (df[~df['Group'].isin(idx)])
   Group Morph
0      1     S
1      1     E
2      1     E
```

One row solution:

```
print (df[~df['Group'].isin(df.loc[df['Morph'].isin(['U',np.nan]), 'Group'].unique())])
   Group Morph
0      1     S
1      1     E
2      1     E
```

Comparing solutions - there are big differences - `groupby` solution is 100 times slowier, but mainly it depends of your real data:

```
np.random.seed(123)
#1M df
N = 1000000
L2 = ['S','E','U',np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':np.random.randint(100000, size=N), 
                   'Morph': np.random.choice(L2, N)})

#print (df)

In [46]: %timeit (df[~df['Group'].isin(df.loc[df['Morph'].isin(['U',np.nan]), 'Group'].unique())])
1 loop, best of 3: 372 ms per loop

In [47]: %timeit (df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: (~x.Morph.isin(['U',np.nan]).any() )))
1 loop, best of 3: 34.7 s per loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As I use big catalogues, a time difference of 100x can change my life, thanks! :)